# How to understand "the cold" here?

Tags: meaning

> I can't sleep for ***the cold***.

I wonder: Does "the cold " here refer to "a mild, very common illness" or "the cold weather"?

Comment: Some of your examples sentences with _for_ seem a bit contrived. Without context one cannot be sure, but I would assume that here "cold" refers to temperature rather than health. I would say "I can't sleep _because_ of the cold" or "because I am cold".

Comment: Doesn't sound contrived to me. Perfectly good idiomatic English, if a little dated.

Answer (score 1):

Without further context, the second seems to be the unmarked (usual) reading:

```
I can't sleep because of the cold [weather]
```

If it were because of illness, I would expect

```
I can't sleep for a cold
                  ^
```

... because it's non-specific. For specific ailments:

```
I can't sleep for the flu/gout/gout
                  ^
```

Comment: Why a cold is non-specific ,but the flu/gout are specific?

Comment: @user48070 It's to do with whether you think the person you're talking to (or writing for) knows what you're talking about. While "a cold" ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cold?showCookiePolicy=true)) refers to a collection of symptoms, flu and gout refer to specific conditions. It might be somewhat idiomatic.